# Comment form not display properly?

Tags: theme-development, comments, comment-form

I want to display comment form in my blog page `comment_form()` work properly but its display like that:

> Comment
>
> name
>
> email
>
> website

But this form should be display like that

> Name
>
> email
>
> website
>
> comment

I was tried most of demo and snippets but they are not worked. So anyone have an idea about that.

Here is my 
**comments.php**

```
    <?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage XXXXX
 * @since Claster 1.0
 * 
 * Comments Template
 * Created by CMSMasters
 * 
 */


if (!empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) && 'comments.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) {
    die(__('Please do not load this page directly. Thanks!', 'cmsmasters'));
}

if (post_password_required()) { 
    echo '<p class="nocomments">' . __('This post is password protected. Enter the password to view comments.', 'cmsmasters') . '</p>';

    return;
}

if (have_comments()) {
    echo '<aside id="comments">' . "\n" . 
        '<h6>';

    comments_number(__('No Comments', 'cmsmasters'), __('Comment', 'cmsmasters') . ' (1)', __('Comments', 'cmsmasters') . ' (%)');

    echo '</h6>' . "\n";

    if (get_previous_comments_link() || get_next_comments_link()) {
        echo '<aside class="project_navi" role="navigation">' . "\n\t" . 
            '<span class="fl">' . "\n\t\t";

        previous_comments_link('&larr; ' . __('Older Comments', 'cmsmasters'));

        echo "\n\t" . '</span>' . "\n\t" . 
        '<span class="fr">' . "\n\t\t";

        next_comments_link(__('Newer Comments', 'cmsmasters') . ' &rarr;');

        echo "\n\t" . '</span>' . "\r" . 
        '</aside>' . "\n";
    }

    echo '<ol class="commentlist">' . "\n";

    wp_list_comments(array( 
        'type' => 'comment', 
        'callback' => 'mytheme_comment' 
    ));

    echo '</ol>' . "\n";

    if (get_previous_comments_link() || get_next_comments_link()) {
        echo '<aside class="project_navi" role="navigation">' . "\n\t" . 
            '<span class="fl">' . "\n\t\t";

        previous_comments_link('&larr; ' . __('Older Comments', 'cmsmasters'));

        echo "\n\t" . '</span>' . "\n\t" . 
        '<span class="fr">' . "\n\t\t";

        next_comments_link(__('Newer Comments', 'cmsmasters') . ' &rarr;');

        echo "\n\t" . '</span>' . "\r" . 
        '</aside>' . "\n";
    }

    echo '</aside>';
}

if (comments_open()) {
    $form_fields =  array( 
        'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . "\n" . 
            '<label for="author">' . __('Name', 'cmsmasters') . (($req) ? ' <span class="required color_3">*</span>' : '') . '</label>' . "\n" . 
            '<input type="text" id="author" name="author" value="' . esc_attr($commenter['comment_author']) . '" size="30"' . ((isset($aria_req)) ? $aria_req : '') . ' />' . "\n" . 
        '</p>' . "\n", 
        'email' => '<p class="comment-form-email">' . "\n" . 
            '<label for="email">' . __('Email', 'cmsmasters') . (($req) ? ' <span class="required color_3">*</span>' : '') . '</label>' . "\n" . 
            '<input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="' . esc_attr($commenter['comment_author_email']) . '" size="30"' . ((isset($aria_req)) ? $aria_req : '') . ' />' . "\n" . 
        '</p>' . "\n", 
        'url' => '<p class="comment-form-url">' . "\n" . 
            '<label for="url">' . __('Website', 'cmsmasters') . '</label>' . "\n" . 
            '<input type="text" id="url" name="url" value="' . esc_attr($commenter['comment_author_url']) . '" size="30" />' . "\n" . 
        '</p>' . "\n" 
    );

    echo "\n\n";

    comment_form(array( 
        'fields' => apply_filters('comment_form_default_fields', $form_fields), 
        'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment">' . 
            '<textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="28" rows="6"></textarea>' . 
        '</p>', 
        'must_log_in' => '<p class="must-log-in">' . __('You must be', 'cmsmasters') . ' <a href="' . wp_login_url(apply_filters('the_permalink', get_permalink())) . '">' . __('logged in', 'cmsmasters') . '</a> ' . __('to post a comment', 'cmsmasters') . '.</p>' . "\n", 
        'logged_in_as' => '<p class="logged-in-as">' . __('Logged in as', 'cmsmasters') . ' <a href="' . admin_url('profile.php') . '">' . $user_identity . '</a>. <a class="all" href="' . wp_logout_url(apply_filters('the_permalink', get_permalink())) . '" title="' . __('Log out of this account', 'cmsmasters') . '">' . __('Log out?', 'cmsmasters') . '</a></p>' . "\n", 
        'comment_notes_before' => '<p class="comment-notes">' . __('Your email address will not be published. Required fields are marked', 'cmsmasters') . ' <span class="required color_3">*</span></p>' . "\n", 
        'comment_notes_after' => '', 
        'id_form' => 'commentform', 
        'id_submit' => 'submit', 
        'title_reply' => __('Leave a Reply', 'cmsmasters'), 
        'title_reply_to' => __('Leave your comment to', 'cmsmasters'), 
        'cancel_reply_link' => __('Cancel Reply', 'cmsmasters'), 
        'label_submit' => __('Submit Comment', 'cmsmasters') 
    ));
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have inside your `comment.php` as that is where it is to control the inputs etc.

Comment: sure @CoderSte i will post code

Comment: May I ask if your following a tutorial on making a comment page?

Comment: http://crunchify.com/wordpress-comment-form-customization/ @CoderSte

Comment: If this is just a basic comment form then this is much harder than what you need xD I can post the code to my `comment.php` in an answer :)

Comment: I've added my answer :)

Answer (score 5):

**Comment.php**

The way I see your `comment.php` seems messy and more complex than it needs to be, you can post this piece of code to in your `comment.php` and it should work okay.

```
<?php 
/**
 * If the current post is protected by a password and
 * the visitor has not yet entered the password we will
 * return early without loading the commend
 */
if (post_password_required()) {
    return;
}

?>

    <?php

        // Do not delete these lines
        if (!empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) && 'comments.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
        die ('Please do not load this page directly. Thanks!');
        ?>

        <!-- You can start editing here. -->
    <div id="comment-area">
        <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>

            <h4 class="comments">Comments <?php comments_number( '( 0 )', '<span class="responses">( 1 )</span>', '<span class="response">( % )</span>' ); ?></h4>

            <?php the_comments_navigation(); ?>

            <ol class="commentlist">
                <?php 
                wp_list_comments( array(
                    'callback'      => 'custom_comment_callback',
                    'style'         => 'ol',
                )); 
                ?>
            </ol>

            <?php the_comments_navigation(); ?>

    </div>

        <?php else : // this is displayed if there are no comments so far ?>

        <?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>
        <!-- If comments are open, but there are no comments. -->

        <?php else : // comments are closed ?>
            <!-- If comments are closed. -->
            <p class="nocomments">Comments are closed.</p>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>

            <div id="respond">

                <h4 class="comment-title">
                    <?php comment_form_title( 'Leave a Comment', 'Leave a Reply to %s' );?>
                </h4>

                <div class="cancel-comment-reply">
                    <small><?php cancel_comment_reply_link(); ?></small>
                </div>

        <?php if ( get_option('comment_registration') && !$user_ID ) : ?>
                <p>You must be <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>">logged in</a> to post a comment.</p>

        <?php else : ?>

            <form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform">
                <?php if ( $user_ID ) : ?>

                    <p class="logged-in">Logged in as 
                        <span class="login-user"><?php echo $user_identity; ?></span>. 
                        <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(get_permalink()); ?>">Log out <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                    </p>

                <?php else : ?>

                    <p class="comment-form-author fa">
                        <input type="text" name="author" class="author" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" <?php if ($req) echo "aria-required='true'"; ?> placeholder="Name"/>
                    </p>

                    <p class="comment-form-email fa">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="email" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2" <?php if ($req) echo "aria-required='true'"; ?> placeholder="E-Mail"/>
                    </p>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <!--<p><small><strong>XHTML:</strong> You can use these tags: <code><?php echo allowed_tags(); ?></code></small></p>-->

                    <p class="comment-form-comment fa">
                        <textarea name="comment" class="comment" rows="7" tabindex="3" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
                    </p>

                    <p class="form-submit">
                        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="submit" tabindex="4" value="Post Comment" />
                        <?php comment_id_fields(); ?>
                    </p>
                <?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>
            </form>

            <?php endif; // If registration required and not logged in ?>
        </div>

    <?php endif; // if you delete this the sky will fall on your head ?>
```

Bear in mind this is without the Website input but that is easy to add :D

**Single.php**

Inside your `single.php` file you can add this line of code to check if there the comments are open and then display the `comment_template`

```
<?php 
    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
        comments_template();
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks @CoderSte But  `comment_form()` automatically create form so why are you write HTMl. I was update my comments.php

Comment: Yeah that is a comment-form where users can input their own name and email and it works the same but this way you can add more inputs to the field :)

Comment: yes that is right and good concept but i want customize my code, Is that possible or not.

Comment: What do you mean by customize your code? What do you exactly want to do with it?